# Receive raspberry stream in C#

Tags: networking, streaming-video

I can receive a stream from the raspberry using mplayer and netcat.

On the raspberry: raspivid -t 999999 -o - | nc [ip address] 5001

On Windows:  nc -L -p 5001 | mplayer -fps 31 -cache 1024 -

So far so good, but now I can get mplayer, in my C# form, to work but don't know how to tell it to receive a stream from my local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have already nailed the RPi part of the issue, and is only missing the windows component.

As with your netcat setup, you need to create a listening socket in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627031/listen-for-data-on-tcp-port-c-sharp

I suggest you try to ask for implementation details on stackoverflow, as this problem is highly relevant there and you will get some really good answers.